# Angular 7 change boolean true to false in client side. html page of Angular Application

Tags: asp.net, angular, angular7

I am using the given Method to push items in to array named Edudata. when data is pushed my boolean variable named isSuccessful becomes true

when data is pushed my boolean variable named isSuccessful becomes true. On client side I checked in ngif condition if issuccessful is true table is generating

```
saveEducation(educ: Education) {
this.eduData.push(educ);
this.isSuccessful = true;
}


<table class="table-responsive" *ngIf="isSuccessful">
<button mat-raised-button color="Primary" 
(click)="saveEducationtoTable(education)">Add</button>
<table class="table-responsive"  *ngIf="isSuccessful">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>
Degree Name
</th>
<th>
 Institute Name
</th>
<th>
Start Date
</th>
<th>
 End Date
</th>
<th>


   <td class="td-input">
          <mat-label class="label-margin">Select Degree</mat-label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <mat-select name="degree" [(ngModel)]="education.degree_Name" 
 placeholder="--Select Degree--"
       required>
            <mat-option value="No formal education">No formal 
education</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="Primary education">Primary education</mat- 
option>
            <mat-option value="Secondary education">Secondary education or 
high school</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="Vocational qualification">Vocational 
qualification</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="Bachelor's degree">Bachelor's degree (14 
years)</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="Bachelor's degree">Bachelor's degree (16 
years)</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="Master's degree">Master's degree</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="Doctorate or higher">Doctorate or 
  higher</mat-option>
          </mat-select>

    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </mat-form-field>
  <!-- Choose Start Date For Degree Date Picker -->
  <mat-form-field class="inputClass">
<table class="inputClass">
 <tr>
 <td class="td-input">
  <mat-label class="label-margin">Start Date</mat-label>
 </td>
 <td>

        <input matInput  [matDatepicker]="pickerStart" name="start_Date" 
  placeholder="Choose a Start date" 
  [(ngModel)]="education.start_Date"required disabled>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerStart" required> 
       </mat- 
   datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #pickerStart disabled="false" required></mat- 
 datepicker>

</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
<!-- Choose End Date For Degree Date Picker -->
 </mat-form-field>
 <mat-form-field class="inputClass">
  <table class="inputClass">
    <tr>
      <td class="td-input">
        <mat-label class="label-margin">End Date</mat-label>
      </td>
      <td>
              <input matInput  
        [matDatepicker]="pickerEnd"name="start_Date" 
    placeholder="Choose a End date"[(ngModel)]="education.end_Date" 
  required 
  disabled>
              <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerEnd"required> 
  </mat-datepicker-toggle>
              <mat-datepicker #pickerEnd disabled="false"required></mat- 
  datepicker>

      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </mat-form-field>
 <!-- Select Institute dropdown -->
  <mat-form-field class="inputClass">
<table class="inputClass">
  <tr>
    <td class="td-input">
      <mat-label class="label-margin">Select Institution</mat-label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <mat-select name="institution" 
     [(ngModel)]="education.Institution_Name" placeholder="--Select 
       Institution--" required>
            <mat-option value = "NUST" >NUST</mat-option>
            <mat-option value = "IIUI">IIUI</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
         </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </mat-form-field>
```

Now when table is generated i want to make isSuccessful false again. so that when user entered data second time into array then isSuccessful should become true otherwise false

Comment: you can use `timeout` e.g after some seconds or ms make `isSuccessful` false again

Comment: 1. There is something wrong about your implementation. for ` when tbale is generated i want to make isSuccessful false again` :  why are you showing the table when you have to hide it after the `table` is generated ? 2. I can't see any code where the USER IS ENTERING the data. Please provide a demo code on stackblitz.com or add some more code in your question

Comment: as per your comment, u can try resetting the array `this.eduData = []` on `(ngModelChange)` and then call `saveEducation()` with correct data

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to do this at all. If you set isSuccessful to false, your table will disappear, which I assume you don't want! If the table is bound to the data in the controller, it will be regenerated live when new data is pushed.

You need to create a new education object when the user clicks add. Something like:

```
saveEducation(educ: Education) {
    this.eduData.push(educ);
    this.education = new Education();
}
```

Comment: problem is that when after 1st enter User again fills the form. Table data is converted to latest one which i dont want. I want new row each time in table when user fills the form and presses the add button

Comment: OK, so something else is causing your array to be reset rather than added to. The way you are going about it with 'isSuccessful' won't work. Please post more of the controller and view code.

Comment: I have added code in question . When add button is pressed table is generated on function calling

Comment: problem is when user second time filled form tables entries updated by latest values and both rows becomes identical. when user filled form third time tabler again updates by latest data and three rows becomes identical

Comment: Where is the input field for the user to enter education data?

Comment: I am devleped form for taking users education data. like from bachelors to inter and then to matriculation. so If user first enters matric data. after press add button table should contain one row of matric data. then user enters bachelors data and after add button row is added in table containing bachelors data

Comment: You have a data modelling problem. Your ng-model is a field of the 'education' object. When you click add, you add the whole object 'education' to the eduData array - that causes it to be added over and over. Instead, you need to create a new object each time the user clicks add, and push that object to the eduData array.

Comment: will you please help in creation of dynamic object then?

Comment: I didnt getting any solution for it

Comment: Do you know how to create a new Education object in code?

Comment: Yes I know but in this scenario I need dynamic object creation because user can enter unlimited records

Comment: Yep, so every time they click Add, in the code, push the object they added to the array, then set the object in scope to a new Education object. That will clear the fields, and allow the user to enter new details.

Comment: Ok I am going to try this one

Comment: Brother I didnt getting any help. I am new to angular if you could help me out in setting objecyt in scope

Comment: There should be an ng-for somewhere in your template to repeat the rows of the eduData array. You seem still not to have put in all the code.

Comment: I have done it. Problem is that table is in form tag. I put that outside and that works